# Convert JSON formatted NSString to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I have a string I'm getting from JSON.

```
{
    "Audit_Description": "Request Approved",
    "Module_Name": "Resource Request",
    "Field_DisplayName": null",
    "Previous_Value": Education",
    "Current_Value": Employment",
    "Modified_Timestamp": "08-02-2013"
 },
 {
    "Audit_Description": "Request Approved",
    "Module_Name": "Resource Request",
    "Field_DisplayName": null",
    "Previous_Value": null",
    "Current_Value": null",
    "Modified_Timestamp": "08-02-2013"
}
```

I want to parse data. From `JSON`, data come in `NSString` as above.
I want to extract them as key pair value. But I am not able to parse them.
This should be convert in `NSMutableDictionary` like
for key `"Audit_Description"` value should be `"Request Approved"`

Output:

```
  @{
      @"Audit_Description" : @"Request Approved",
      @"Module_Name" = @"Resource Request",
      @"Field_DisplayName" : <null>,
      @"Previous_Value" : @"Education",
      @"Current_Value" : @"Employment",
      @"Modified_Timestamp" : @"08-02-2013"
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

// access the dictionaries
NSMutableDictionary *dict = arr[0];
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in arr) {
  // do something using dictionary
}
```

That creates a mutable dictionary thanks to NSJSONReadingMutableContainers.

Comment: I get mutableArray with 2 dict,How should i extract each object from array.I try for typecasting but not done.Their are not keys and value pair

Comment: That's because your structure is an array with dictionaries. You can loop them to get each one, or access a position directly, like any array: arr[0].

Comment: damn this works? hell yeah totally using this next time thanks!